# How to get a file from client browser to server php?

Tags: php, server, client

Ok, perhaps this is a simple or obvious question but how do you take a file and have the server read the data? I am new to some aspects of web dev but I assumed that you could read the contents through the client/browser and then  manipulate the data on the server through php?... So if thats not the case do you have to upload the file, so download it to the server and then have it read the data, delete the file and then manipulate the data? Trying to find some sample code, but everything from the W3 to PHP tutorials is about if you have the file locally. I plan to have users creating data on their machine, cvs file, and then somehow have it uploaded/read to the server. I am looking for a concept but if you could point out some example code that would be great too. Thanks

btw I use PHP and HTML, I saw some java stuff but I'am not that familiar with it.

*updated a small code snippet. It will not open a stream/file as the $file is just a name on a client machine and not located on my server. I thought it would load it in.....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php

if(isset($_POST["cvsfile"])){
$file = $_POST["cvsfile"];

  $handle = fopen($file, 'r');
   if (!$handle)
    die('Cannot open  file.');
  $rows = array();
 //Read the file as csv
  while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

      $rows[] =  $data;

   }

     print_r($array);

  fclose($handle);
}
?>

<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    CVS File:
    <input type="file" name="cvsfile">
    <input type="submit" value="file" name="submit">
 </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can access the tmp folder where it is stored use the content and then dont upload it

Comment: You haven't provided any of your code, so it's hard to give a full answer. What I can tell you is that you will want to send the file to the server via a form POST or an AJAX call (JavaScript code on your client page) to an endpoint on your server. Then you can read through the file on the server. Or, you can send all the raw data from the csv to the server as the payload, no file needed.

Comment: Could you point me in the direction how to send all the raw data from the csv to the server as the payload? I am so lost how to connect/manipulate the client file.  All the fopens/freads don't work as the php is on the server not the client.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function CSVImport($file) {
  $handle = fopen($file, 'r');
  if (!$handle)
      die('Cannot open  file.');
  $rows = array();
  //Read the file as csv
  while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

      $rows[] =  $data;

  }

  fclose($handle);

  return $rows;
}

$csvArray = CSVImport($file['tmp_name']);
```

if you upload a file then it will get  all the data from it without having to download the file anywhere

Comment: Warning: fopen(mydata.csv): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/scsrs/test.php on line 25
Cannot open file.

Comment: I put my output. I am missing something... you mean I need to download the file... sorry for the confusion but I can't read in a file or think I can if isn't not on my machine.  The html file input tag only will give back the name of the file and thats it. I assume I need to bring the file to me the server before I can read it in, which does not makes since as if I could read it and send it that would be so much more efficient.

Comment: Edit the post with your HTML in it... have you put enctype="multipart/form-data" on your form?